# remove line console line breaks @ out-file

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following PowerShell command:

```
dir -r -include *.log | Select-String "Some pattern" | Out-File .\findings.out
```

If I open the findings.out file the "redirected" loglines include additional line breaks, that were not included in the original logfiles, e.g.:

Original logline:

```
xxxx.log:3977:2016-05-03T07:39:13.847+02:00; INFO ; hello world
```

Logline findings.out:

```
xxx.log:3977:2016-05-03T07:
39:13.847+02:00; INFO ; 
hello world
```

Any hints?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide sample input and pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the following:

```
$File = "$env:TEMP\test.txt"
```

All content on one line because the whole string is now quoted between '`'`' single quotes (or double quotes '`"`'):

```
'xxx.log:3977:2016-05-03T07:39:13.847+02:00; INFO ; hello world' | Out-File $File
```

Only 'hello world' is in the file:

```
'xxx.log:3977:2016-05-03T07:39:13.847+02:00'; 'INFO'; 'hello world' | Out-File $File
```

Because PowerShell sees the following:

```
Write-Output 'xxx.log:3977:2016-05-03T07:39:13.847+02:00'
Write-Output 'INFO'
Write-Output 'hello world' | Out-File $File
```

As you can see, only the last line is written to the CmdLet `Out-File`.

The last two statements are the same. The semicolon '`;`' is a PowerShell code seperator. So it's the same if you write it on multiple lines without the semicolon or on one line with semicolons between the strings

Comment: But the file contains the complete log-entry. Not only 'hello world'. I've found out if I use `Add-Content` the complete log-entry is written as expected.

Comment: You can also use `Out-File $File -Append` which will append all data to the file.